# Is there a way to make dictionary keys point to original variable?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, pointers, assign

I've been facing a problem with class attributes and dictionaries in Python. I have the following class:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.dictionary = {'key': self.a}

    def check(self, string):
        print("Before: ",self.a)
        self.dictionary[string] += 2
        print("After (Dictionary): ",self.dictionary[string])
        print("After (Original variable): ",self.a)
```

And then i create an object test from it:

```
test = Test(5)
```

The problem is: when i use the check method:

```
test.check('key')
```

The output is:

```
Before:  5
After (Dictionary):  7
After (Original variable):  5
```

What i expected was to be able to change the attribute `self.a` inside the class by changing the dictionary `self.dictionary` value where i assigned the `self.a` attribute. But what's happening is that the original attribute `self.a` hasn't changed, yet the value inside the dictionary, that was supposed to be `self.a`, has.

Can anyone explain to me why this happens? I assume the dict is creating a copy of `self.a` as the value for the `'key'`. Is there any way i can have the value of the dictionary point to the original variable `self.a` so i can change it by changing the value of the dictionary?

**Edit:**

Thank you, guys! I understand now that i was expecting an incorrect behavior from the dictionary. I shall try another approach.

Comment: the dictionary is another element, an not a reference of self.a

Comment: Because you are changing the value of dictionary, not instance variable value

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to the property of class attributes but rather to how dictionaries work in Python and to the fact that integers are **immutable**. To illustrate it, the same happens when you do:

```
value = 5
dictionary = {"key": value}

dictionary["key"] += 2

print(value)
# > 5

print(dictionary["key"])
# > 7
```

> It is important here to note that this does not work because `self.a` is an integer which is an **immutable** type in Python. This means that you will not be changing the integer's value by doing something like `self.dictionary[string] += 2`.

Now, what would work well for your problem would be something like this, where you declare a list instead of an integer to keep the **mutability** property:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = [a] # instead of self.a = a
        self.dictionary = {'key': self.a}

    def check(self, string):
        print("Before: ",self.a[0])
        self.dictionary[string][0] += 2
        print("After (Dictionary): ",self.dictionary[string][0])
        print("After (Original variable): ",self.a[0])

test = Test(5)

# > Before:  5
# > After (Dictionary):  7
# > After (Original variable):  7
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.a` points to an `int` object and ints are immutable. I.E they cannot be changed. when you create the dictionary object you are saying point this key to the same place that self.a points to. When you then change the value that the dictionary key points to since `int` is immutable a new into object is created at a new memory location so now the dict key points to that new memory location and not at the same memory location as `self.a` still points to.

so you now have self.a pointing at the memory location holding int 5 and the dict key pointing to a different memory location holding int 7.

**UPDATE**

update based on your comment, the only way to make self.a and the dict key value to point to the same item all the time is to use a mutable data type like list for example. since lists are mutable then when you change the value in the list, both self.a and dict still point to the same list and only the value inside it was changed. however all references to the int value need to access it through the first element in the list

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = [a]
        self.dictionary = {'key': self.a}

    def check(self, string):
        print("Before: ", self.a[0])
        self.dictionary[string][0] += 2
        print("After (Dictionary): ", self.dictionary[string][0])
        print("After (Original variable): ", self.a[0])


test = Test(5)
test.check('key')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Before:  5
After (Dictionary):  7
After (Original variable):  7
```

However as i said in my comment. For what reason would you need to have two different attributes / references to the same value in your class instance. chances are what ever your trying to achieve there is a better way to do it than an approach like this

Comment: Ooooh thanks, i see it. So, is there a way to make the dictionary key point to the `self.a` variable? Suppose i have more than 1 attribute: `self.a`, `self.b`, `self.c`.. . I wanted to use the dictionary so i could access any of the attributes by using something like `self.dict['variable1']`, `self.dict['variable2']`, etc.

Comment: you will have the same problem either way round, self.a would point to the immutable value that the dict key pointed to which is an immutable int so when the value of the key is changed self.a would still be left pointing to the old value. I think you need to think about what are you actually trying to acheive. why do you need to store the same value twice in two seperate attributes in the class?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, There are 2 instance variable of class Test is :
self.a = a
self.dictionary = {'key': self.a}

In check method you are changing /updating self.dictionary variable and not on self.a 
(self.dictionary[string] += 2)
self.dictionary and self.a are two different variable if you want to update self.a than following can be done:

```
class Test:
def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a
    self.dictionary = {'key': self.a}

def check(self, string):
    print("Before: ",self.a)
    self.a+=2
    self.dictionary[string] = self.a
    print("After (Dictionary): ",self.dictionary[string])
    print("After (Original variable): ",self.a)
```

Output will be :

```
('Before: ', 5)
('After (Dictionary): ', 7)
('After (Original variable): ', 7)
```